# Does Tor provide TCP-like reliability?

Tags: socks

I need to transfer some data to a Tor hidden service through a custom protocol. If I did it in TCP, a successful `send(socket_to_server, data, data_length, 0);` would mean that all data had been written and all the necessary ACKs received.

Tor works as a SOCKS proxy, so it is TCP-like to some extent. Is it possible for Tor to silently lose data intended for a hidden service, so I have to implement an ACK message myself?

Comment: I believe that if you're going to attempt to send raw socket communications via the SOCKS proxy, you would want to use an existing protocol like HTTP to handle the proper response (or like you said, write your own). You're correct that you won't receive the raw ACK back because only special TCP packets are being sent via the client.